# Создание RAID 1 для Windows server 2012 R2 на матплате ASUS

Tags: raid, asus, windows-server-2012

Имеется проблема с созданием RAID 1 на материнской плате ASUS G5S2FN015777 (Z10PA-D8 серверная) на основе 2-х SSD. То есть в BIOS из 2-х SSD sumsung SATA 3.0 создаётся RAID 1, который на уровне железа виден. Когда же доходит дело до установки Windows server 2012 RAID на SSD из-под установочника не виден. Если же не создавать RAID, то в установочнике видны два SSD. Пробовал переустановить драйвер контроллера для создания RAID - не помогло. У кого какие есть соображения?

Comment: На старте установщика нужно "подсунуть" ему драйвер для дискового контроллера матплаты именно в RAID-версии. Правильный драйвер выберите на странице https://www.asus.com/ru/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z10PAD8/HelpDesk_Download/ в зависимости от конкретной матери.

Comment: По той же ссылке - переключитесь в подраздел "Руководства и Документация". Загрузите документ "Z10PA-D8 Series User Guide for English". Откройте его. Прочитайте и выполните инструкции из разделов 6.1.1 и 6.1.2.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, выручаете меня не первый раз)Всё заработало.